# KiCad Blender Material modifications were not applied

Tags: materials

I´m new to Blender and I try to pimp one of my PCB projects with it. So I grab [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Pjr0xkuyhU&ab_channel=thereoughtabe) tutorial and import my PCB. However, I got stuck in the material chapter because the modifications didn´t work.

This is the transistor without modifications and when I set "Metallic" to 1 nothing happens.

[image]

What might be the reason for it? I can also share the Blender project when necessary.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Is it the only component you have issues with ?

Comment: And what do you mean "nothing happens"? Do you simply not see a difference (immediately)? Could the difference be too subtle to notice?

Comment: Hi @StefLAncien,
I´ve uploaded the file. With "nothing happens" I mean that I don´t see any difference. However I only tested this single component. So I´m not sure if this issue happens to more than one component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

The material assigned to the casing of the transistor of interest is *SHAPE_2797.001*. Setting properties *Metallic* to 1 and *Roughness* to 0 seems to render consistent results:

[image: Metallic to 1]

To identify the material assigned to a face, go to *Edit Mode* with *Select Mode* set to *Face*. Open the *Material Properties* panel on the GUI right hand side. In the *3D Viewport* pick a face. Its material is alighted in the *Material Properties* panel. You can get all the faces sharing this material by clicking the *Select* button (between *Assign* and *Deselect*).

[image: How to select a material]

Comment: Thank you! How do I figure out the correct material?

Comment: *Side note:* it might worth to rename materials based on the associated components.